# finding negative cycle with fewest edges

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

I want to find the shortest negative cycle (i.e. fewest edges) in a graph, if it exists. I was reading [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54836/finding-shortest-negative-cycle) and it seems like Bellman-Ford can do this, if I run it starting from each vertex? So to clarify - is the idea that if the shortest negative cycle has N edges, and I happen to start from a vertex on this cycle, then after N steps of Bellman-Ford I will detect/find this cycle?

Comment: Bellman-Ford will find the cycle with the smallest sum of weights, which is not necessarily the shortest, if you are defining shortest at the smallest number of edge traversals.

Comment: @Mitch Suppose there exists a negative cycle A-B-C-A with fewest edges. Let w(A,B)=-1, w(B, C)=-1, and w(C,A) = 1. I initialize from A, then after 2 iterations, I see d(C)=-2. After 1 more iteration, I see d(A)=d(C)+w(C,A)=-1, indicating a negative cycle with 3 edges. Even if there is another negative cycle with more edges and lower weight, I won't actually detect it until more iterations, right? So I can conclude that A-B-C-A is the negative cycle with fewest edges?